# In Google Sheets Scripts, how do I setValues with two array variables into two columns

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script that has two variables that are arrays taking data from separate sheets, then using setValues to paste them both, side by side, into two columns.

so it would be:

```html
var range1 = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var range2 = sheet2.getRange(2,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var numRows = rankSheet.getRange(2,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),1).getNumRows();

sheet3.getRange(sheet3.getLastRow()+1,1,numRows,2).setValues([sheet1][sheet2])
```

I get errors doing this though and I can't find any documentation on how to stack two separate ranges next to each other into two columns. I've tried "[[sheet1][sheet2]]", "[sheet1],[sheet2]", most variations of those two, creating a combined array. Concatenating them has normally stacked them instead of put them side by side. I can get them to print separately with two setValues lines but then they don't stack side to side (because of the "getLastRow()+1")

Comment: Can I ask you about the variables of ``sheet1`` and ``sheet2``?

Comment: Sure @Tanaike! I know I didn't declare them but they're just to suggest that I'm getting the ranges from different sheets instead of data points right next to each other.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand about the value of ``sheet1`` and ``sheet2`` from your reply.